# Cannot retrieve values from Shared Preferences

Tags: android

Below is the method updateweather . I can change the location as well as the temperature unit . On changing the location  the parameters changes but on changing the units nothing changes  even log.i which appears when using location as string  doesn't appear when i change location to units.

```
    private void updateWeather() {
    FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.key), getString(R.string.default_value));
    units = prefs.getString("listPref", "1");
    Log.i("LOGGGGGGGGG",units);
    weatherTask.execute(location,format,units);
}
```

**res/xml/settingsdetail**

```
    private void updateWeather() {
    FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.key), getString(R.string.default_value));
    units = prefs.getString("listPref", "1");
    Log.i("LOGGGGGGGGG",units);
    weatherTask.execute(location,format,units);
}
```

**res/values/arrays**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <string-array name="listArray">
    <item>Metric</item>
    <item>Imperial</item>

    </string-array>

    <string-array name="listValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>

    </string-array>
    </resources>
```

**The entire code**

```
    public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;
String units;
String format = "json";

int numDays = 7;

public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        updateWeather();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source and
    // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout  ID.
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                    new ArrayList<String>());

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2Activity.class)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void updateWeather() {
    FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String location = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.key), getString(R.string.default_value));
    units = prefs.getString("listPref", "1");
    Log.i("LOGGGGGGGGG", units);
    weatherTask.execute(location, format, units);
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateWeather();
}

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
     * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
     */
    private String getReadableDateString(long time) {
        // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
        // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
        SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
        return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
     */
    private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
        // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
        long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
        long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

        String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
        return highLowStr;
    }

    /**
     * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
     * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
     * <p/>
     * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
     * into an Object hierarchy for us.
     */
    private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
            throws JSONException {

        // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
        final String OWM_LIST = "list";
        final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
        final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
        final String OWM_MAX = "max";
        final String OWM_MIN = "min";
        final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

        JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
        JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

        // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
        // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
        // properly.

        // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
        // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
        // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

        Time dayTime = new Time();
        dayTime.setToNow();

        // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
        int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

        // now we work exclusively in UTC
        dayTime = new Time();

        String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
        for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
            // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
            String day;
            String description;
            String highAndLow;

            // Get the JSON object representing the day
            JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
            // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
            // "this saturday".
            long dateTime;
            // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
            dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay + i);
            day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

            // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
            JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
            description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

            // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
            // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
            JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
            double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
            double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

            highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
            resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
        }
        return resultStrs;

    }

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

        // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
        // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;


        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        if (result != null) {
            mForecastAdapter.clear();
            for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
                mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
            }
            // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: both methods are equal, check if you posted the right code

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova the code where it is used is posted can  you help me with it

Comment: Can you show the code where you save the units variable under the name `listPref` in your SharedPrefferences ? Maybe they are saved with another name

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova sorry sir there were many errors, now it is working

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova :sorry  there were many errors, now it is working, it happens many times: i change the code in android studio but it doesn't reflect the changes then i have to close studio open it again run it then it shows changes , i have a question that whether it is a actual problem faced by others or possibly i am writing the code incorrect and when reopening it i unintentionally (or luckily ) correct it ,, any solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't know way does it happen, but maybe your Android Studio doesn't refresh the project. Instead of reopening the whole Android Studio, you could just rebuild the project and it should help